# Web scraping issue in R

Tags: r

I am trying to extract the data of university rankings for the year 2017 and 2018  from the website name - https://www.topuniversities.com.

I am trying to run a code in R but it's giving me an error.

My code:-

```
library(rvest)
#Specifying the url for desired website to be scrapped
url <-"https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2018/world-ranking#!/page/0/length/-1/sort_by/scores_international_outlook/sort_order/asc/cols/scores"
#Reading the HTML code from the website
webpage <- read_html(url)
vignette("selectorgadget")
ranking_html=html_nodes(url,".namesearch , .sorting_2 , .sorting_asc")
```

error:-

```
Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "character"
```

please help me out to solve the above issue, any suggestion related to web scraping are welcome.

Comment: You probably want `html_nodes(webpage,...)`

Comment: Was just about to comment what Andrew commented. You probably want to use the return from `read_html` instead of just the `url`..

Comment: I'd recommend having a look at the Rcrawler package. It's a lot more robust than rvest in my experience.

Comment: As Andrew pointed out, the correct code should be  `ranking_html=html_nodes(webpage,".namesearch , .sorting_2 , .sorting_asc")`.

Comment: Any other methods of extracting the data from the website . I am running this code, still i am not able to extract the ranking of the universities.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to extract the tables with a different approach :

```
library(pagedown)
library(tabulizer)
chrome_print("https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2018/world-ranking#!/page/0/length/-1/sort_by/scores_international_outlook/sort_order/asc/cols/scores",
             "C:\\...\\table.pdf")

table_Page_2 <- extract_tables("C:\\...\\table.pdf",pages = 2)
table_Page_2
```

After, we have to clean the text of tables, but all the values are there.